# Type checking in @singledispatch doesn't work with import

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I have a *model* namespace and an *event* namespace. Both use each other in app (i.e. for type checking).

The problem is, while importing via *from* syntax, app returns an error with (I suppose) circular dependencies. So I've tried to use juset basic *import* syntax:

```
import domain.event as event
```

But then, when I'll try to check types (or just pass them to @singledispatch decorator), I would get the error:

```
@apply.register(event.IntervalLaunched)
AttributeError: module 'domain.event' has no attribute 'IntervalLaunched'
```

The class is a valid class in file *event.py* and I am 100% positive that the path is correct.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Are you able to instantiate `event.IntervalLaunched` after that import, i.e. ignore @singledispatch for now

Comment: No. I get the same error for every class in this namespace.